# Columns in HTML/CSS + scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to display text in columns inside a horizontal scrolling box.
Basically I have a 600x300 box, and each bit of information is given inside a column, like;

```
Column 1... Column 2 .... Column 3  
Para 1..... Para 2 ...... Para 3
```

Without the dots.

The thing then has to be contained within a horizontal box.

So how is this done?

I used something like the following to create the columns:

```
<style>
.column {
 width:200px;
 float:left
 }
 </style>
<div class="column">
<h2>header text</h2>
<p>paragraph text What if this is longer</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
<h2>header text</h2>
<p>paragraph text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
<h2>header text</h2>
<p>paragraph text</p>
 </div>
```

But I cant' figure out how to contain this all within a box that can scroll horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x: scroll` to your CSS definition.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a container that has `white-space:nowrap` and make the columns `display:inline-block`

```css
.column-container{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.column {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>paragraph text What if this is longer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>paragraph text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>paragraph text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>paragraph text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>paragraph text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```